# Running a same script in sub folders

Tags: r

In my main folder i have many sub folders like AA,BB,CC,DD ...etc. and all folders have a common script named **run_script.R** and i want to run this script in every folder. folder can be any amount.

Its working abut running in first folder only ,but i wanted it to run in every folder.

also when i am using setwd(folder) then showing error
Error in setwd(folder) : cannot change working directory

```
data_folder <- "C:/Users/mosho/Desktop/New folder (2)/"
allfolders <- data.frame(Folders = list.dirs(path = data_folder, recursive = F, full.names = F))
r_scripts <- "run_script.R"

for (folder in allfolders$Folders) {
  #setwd(folder)
  message(folder)
  source(paste0(data_folder,folder,"/",r_scripts))
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on a right path, I did some minor tweaks to your script which will resolve the issue. The points missing in your scripts are;

1. the **allfolders** contains the folder name not the entire explicit path. To set the working directory you need to set give the explicit path, by only calling the folder name will result into error unless you existing working directory is contains that folder. Anyways, its best practice to work with full path names.
2. also to simplify setting up **allfolders** as list for iterator will make your life lot easier than a data frame

Below is my work-out;

I created some dummy folders (DIC01, DIC02, DIC03...) under path "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\TEST MAIN", and placed code **run_script.R** inside each one. This **run_script.R** contains simple code ***print("Hello World !!")***

[image: List of folders]

Next I set initial working directory where to the path where all the folders present i.e. to path "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\TEST MAIN". Next listed the folders/directories present within this path as a list instead of data frame. Next is **for loop** which iterate over list of folder names. Inside we reset the working directory by the folder name and source the R code.

```
data_folder <- "C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\Documents\\TEST MAIN"
setwd(data_folder)
allfolders <- list.dirs(path = data_folder, recursive = F, full.names = F)
r_scripts <- "run_script.R"

for (folder in allfolders) {
print(folder)

setwd(paste0(data_folder,"\\",folder))
source(paste0(data_folder,"\\",folder,"\\",r_scripts))
}
```

The result I get after the execution is something like this. First the name of the directory and then execution result.

[image]

I hope this resolves you problem. If yes **Like/Up vote** the answer and let me know.